# Javascript substr in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I get an error when running the following code using Internet Explorer 8:

```
for (var lang_elem in this.langElems) {
    if (this.langElems.hasOwnProperty(lang_elem)) {  // ignore attributes down the prototype chain
        var www1 = this.langElems[lang_elem].length;
        var xxx1 = line.substr(0, www1);
        var yyy1 = this.langElems[lang_elem];

        if (xxx1 == yyy1) {
            elem_type = lang_elem;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The Debugger stops in the line where xx1 is defined (I obviously defined these three variables for debug purposes) with the following message:

***Unterbrechung bei JScript-Laufzeitfehler - Das Objekt unterstütz diese Eigenschaft oder Methode nicht.***

which translates into

***Break at JScript-runtime error - The object doesn't support the attribute or method.***

I checked, but as to my knowledge, IE8 should support the substr-method. I call it with ***line.substr(0,2)***, which should work (no negativ parameters).

Does anyone have an idea why this error is shown?

Comment: `line` has not been defined in any code you have shown.

Comment: What is `line`? Do a `console.log(typeof line)` right before it. What's the output?

Comment: it's easier to use slice or !! strLong.split(strSubStr)[1];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that `line` is a string at this point? That's normally the message that comes up when a variable is null or undefined. Try sticking a `console.log(line);` just before your call to substr. I also can't see it defined in your example but you might of just trimmed it out by mistake.

Comment: Sorry for providing that little information - its out of a big project and I tried to copy the important parts. Nevertheless you had the right idea Philip. Thanks a lot! The problem was the following: Since IE8 doesn't provide .indexOf() for arrays, I defined it 'by hand'. Now this function was also taken into account when traversing the array using ***for in***. I added ***if (typeof line !== "string") break;*** and now it works as intended. Thanks a lot for your help.